# Image FadeTo animation not working on Android [.net MAUI]

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, maui

I am making a timelapse functionality on .net maui app.

The function works very well when I test it on the Windows Emulator, but when i run the app on the phone, there is no animation, just switching of pictures.

I am using a Grid and two images on each other to make the animation smooth.

**TimelapsePage.xaml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ProjectAlpha.TimeLapsPage"
             Title="TimeLapsPage">




    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="500" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="500" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label 
            Text="Timelapse :)"
            x:Name="lblStatus"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="0"/>
        <Image Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="picField1"  />
        <Image Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="picField2"  />
        <Button Text="Start!" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" HorizontalOptions="Center"
                Clicked="Button_Clicked" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"></Button>
    </Grid>


    <!--<VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label 
            Text="Timelapse :)"
            x:Name="lblStatus"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        <Image x:Name="picField1" HeightRequest="300" WidthRequest="300" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
            
        </Image>
        <Button Text="Start!" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" HorizontalOptions="Center"
                Clicked="Button_Clicked"></Button>
    </VerticalStackLayout>-->
</ContentPage>
```

**TimelapsePage.xaml.cs**:

```
 private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await StartAnimation();
    }

    [Obsolete]
    private async Task StartAnimation()
    {

        Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000), () =>
        {
            picField1.Source = imageSources[i];
            picField1.Opacity = 1;
            picField2.Source = imageSources[i + 1];
            picField2.Opacity = 0;
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread( async () =>
            {
                picField1.FadeTo(0, 1000, Easing.Linear);
             await   picField2.FadeTo(1, 1000, Easing.Linear);
            });
            i++;
            if (i == imageSources.Count - 1) return false;
            else return true;
        });
        
    }

 /*   [Obsolete]
    private async Task StartAnimation() //Old Working version
    {
        picField1.Source = imageSources[0];
        Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(4000), () =>
        {
          //  DebugMsg("1s");
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {
               await picField1.FadeTo(0.5, 2000, Easing.Linear).ContinueWith((arg) =>
               {
                   i++;
                   var currentImageSource = imageSources[i];
                   // Set the new image 
                   Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                   {
                       picField1.Source = currentImageSource;
                       picField1.Opacity = 0.5;
                       await picField1.FadeTo(1, 2000, Easing.Linear);
                   });
               });
            });
            if (i >= imageSources.Count) return false;
            else return true;
        });
 
    }*/
```

I have tried using VerticalStackLayout and one Image with another Animation function (the commented part) but same issue, no animation on the phone app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `await` before `picField1.FadeTo(0, 1000, Easing.Linear);`

To make picture transitions look more natural, you can add a time-lapse momentum.

Please refer to the following code:

```
      Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => 
        {
         
            picField1.FadeTo(0, 1000, Easing.Linear);
            await Task.Delay(100);
            await picField2.FadeTo(1, 1000, Easing.Linear);
        });
```

Comment: Even if i do that there is still no animation at all on Android

Comment: I have tried also picField1.Animate ... also there is no animation on Android

Comment: What model and version of device did you test on? I tested on android 13 emulator.

Comment: I am testing on Galaxy M12 live

Comment: Actually this has worked after i removed the await from the first FadeTo line and added 100ms in the Timer, thanks!